# Difference between '-ться', and '-тся'?

Tags: произношение, правописание

'Тс' already sounds like 'Ть' so why is there a soft sign there? Do I pronounce them both like a soft T?

Comment: Is the question about verb endings?

Comment: The following is incorrect: "Тс' already sounds like 'Ть' " - these two are pronounced as "цц". Смеются произносится как "Смеюцца", смеяться произносится как "смеяцца"

Comment: @Artemix: the original question was: "ть" already sounds like "тс" - because unfortunately some sites teach that soft [t] is pronounced [ts]. So the OP's question began with that misconception. Thus your edit makes no sense and his question (in theory) makes no sense. A less confusing questions (that won't confuse new readers) would be: Why does the verb ending -ться have a soft sign, and how is it pronounced?

Comment: @CocoPop I do not agree with you. I just added dashes to show that question is about endings. In fact it is a common mistake for native speakers as well. Most answers posted prior to my edit are about verb endings. It's a pity that OP does not react nor to comments, nor to answers.

Answer (score 7):

There is no difference in pronunciation but **"ь"** is kept merely for the sake of consistency.

You see, most infinitives end in "**-ть**". And the 3rd person singular/plural end in **-т** :

- to love = *любить*
- he loves = он *любит*

**And now, the magic!** To form a reflexive verb form you add **'сь'** after a vowel and **'ся'** after a consonant. So....

- говорить + ***ся*** = говориться
- говорит + ***ся*** = говорится
- женят + **ся** = женятся

The pair "говориться/говорится" indeed sounds exactly the same because it so happens that 3rd person singular for many "-ить" verbs of the И-conjugation differs from the infinitive only by the hardness of the last consonant.

Answer (score 1):

Actually **ь** is there to indicate the infinitive. However, there is no distinction in pronunciation between -**ться** and -**тся** : they're both pronounced -**тца**.

смея́ться - [**сме•я́т•ца**]    *infinitive*

смеётся - [**сме•йо́т•ца**]  *3rd p. sing.*

смеются - [**сме•ю́т•ца**]   *3rd p. pl.*

Comment: Thanks. Haven't gotten into verb aspects much but I remember the infinitive part about 'ть'.

Comment: This actually has nothing to do with aspect; it's phonetic, not grammatical - both perfective and imperfective verbs have these endings.

Answer (score 1):

It's mostly grammatical and as correctly stated above "ться" usually indicates the infinitive. It is relatively simple to catch the rule by using the following cheat:

- If the word answers the "что делать" question use "ться".
- If the word answers the "что делает / -ют" question you use "тся".

Yes, if there's "ь" in the question word, feel free to use "ться", and the opposite - if there's no "ь" in the question, use тся.

Comment: Yes, this is the way how pupils are taught in Russian schools. But it seems to me that such mnemonics are suitable for native speakers only.

Comment: I am not native speaker and this "cheat" sounds perfectly suitable for me. ;) Requires certain language proficiency, but still.

Comment: Ah, I see :) In fact there are many native speakers on Russian.SE (including myself) and I thought you may be one of them. It's good that this "cheat" works for non-native speakers, because there are some language features that are intuitive for natives (like pairs of verbs of different aspect) and should be learnt by heart by others.

Comment: This cheat is more confusing that the original question! This looks like it would only work if you were Russian.

Comment: Well I am not Russian however I learned it during teenager years and find this explanation clear. I am sorry if it does not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Some native russian have troubles with "-тся"/"-ться" too. 
So we have special site for that: http://tsya.ru/

Comment: Neither your post nor that site you are linking to answers the question in any way.